# Android 4.3 DeviceAdmin error for non owner profile

Tags: android, android-4.3-jelly-bean, device-admin

I am using a Nexus 7 which is updated to Android 4.3.
I have an application which requires Device Admin rights to Lock/ Wipe device.
I have given **Device Admin right** to my application on Owner Profile. So when i switch to another user profile, i can see my application in list of Device Admin apps.
However when i give a Lock command on this non Owner user profile, i get the exception as

> "java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin owned by uid XXXXXX".

`DevicePolicyManager isActiveAdmin ()` method also returns true on this profile still it fails to take action and crashes the application.

I assume that once device admin is set for Owner user profile, its automatically applied to all other user profiles.Any idea then why is this happening ?
Also, is there any documentation that points out on what care should my application take in order to handle Multiple user profiles in case my app requires device admin rights

Comment: "I assume that once device admin is set for Owner user profile, its automatically applied to all other user profiles" -- I certainly would not assume that. I would assume that other profiles, particularly restricted ones, have no ability to work with device admins. That being said, I am not aware of any documentation in this space.

Comment: what i said was based on observation on my Nexus 7 . I will check forcing acivation of DeviceAdmin on other profiles and update here.

Comment: Try uninstalling the app, and reinstalling the apk on that user account, and then adding it as a device administrator and launching the app.

Comment: This option does not seem user friendly at all. Still i will gv it a try

Answer (score 8):

Have you set in device_admin_sample.xml what admin policy comply with your App expected behaviour?

Set the admin paramenters as

```
 android:label="@string/enterprise_device_admin" 
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"> 
     android:resource="@xml/enterprise_device_admin" />
```

Here is a typical content for your file device_admin_sample.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".app.DeviceAdminSample"
        android:label="@string/activity_sample_device_admin">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<receiver android:name=".app.DeviceAdminSample$DeviceAdminSampleReceiver"
    android:label="@string/sample_device_admin"
    android:description="@string/sample_device_admin_description"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin"
        android:resource="@xml/device_admin_sample" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Further reading with step by step instructions that is also worth checking:

- [Make your application a device administrator](http://rootfs.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/android-make-your-application-a-device-administrator/)
- [Device Administration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)